# FileHandler - java.logging.util no carriage return

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I'm trying to print log information on file using java.logging.util. This solution is working, but the information from the log doesn't show with the carriage return.
My code:

Main

```
   String url ="opc.tcp://DEV85:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer";
   MyFormatter formatter=new MyFormatter();
   fh = new FileHandler("C:/tmp/MyLogFile.log",true);
   logger.addHandler(fh);
   fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
   
   doSomething else()
   
   EndpointDescription[] endpoints = myClient.discoverEndpoints(url);   


   for(EndpointDescription e: endpoints) {
        //System.out.println(e);
        
        logger.info(e.toString());
    }
```

Formatter Class

```
public class MyFormatter extends Formatter {
    
    // Create a DateFormat to format the logger timestamp.
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1000);
        builder.append(df.format(new Date(record.getMillis()))).append(" - ");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getSourceClassName()).append(".");
        builder.append(record.getSourceMethodName()).append("] - ");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getLevel()).append("] - ");
        builder.append(formatMessage(record));
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"));
        //builder.append("\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

The output is just on a line. I've found out online some solution, but  nothing it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

One quick nit, the SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe so you don't what to store it as a object or static reference.  Create a new instance each call or use the [java.time.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package.  Fix this so it is not causing any phantom issues.

> This solution is working, but the information from the log doesn't show with the carriage return.

Open the file with a text editor that can show whitespace characters.  Your formatter code looks correct. You need to double check that the viewer you are using may be just rendering the text incorrectly (Notepad).  Worst case use a FileInputStream and read raw bytes as hex.  Should be able to see the hex values for the [line separator](https://www.asciitable.com/).  Your unit test of just the formatter itself should be able to verify that the line separator is present.

The other issue is that you have to prove that your formatter is being used.  You are opening the file for append so it would be possible for other formatters to insert their data in the same file.  Consider overriding getHead and getTail to generate a unique id and place that in your formatter for testing.  This will show the start and stop of your formatter.

Also the [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) can support this format but it is a global setting and can't be customized for each object.